# Adding np array objects to a list

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to append a sub image which is numpy array objects to a list.

```py
    temp = []
    for color in COLOUR_RANGE:
       #Some code to extract the color region which is represented in numpy 
        if cv2.contourArea(coloured_cnt) > 400:
            
            x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(coloured_cnt)

            coloursRect = cv2.cvtColor(img[y:y+h, x:x+w], cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            coloursRect_1D = np.vstack(coloursRect)/255

            temp.append(coloursRect_1D.copy())
            print(len(temp))
            print(type(temp))
```

But the length of the list is added by two every loop.

```
2
<class 'list'>
4
<class 'list'>
6
<class 'list'>
8
<class 'list'>
10
```

However, if i create a new list as follows

```
    temp = [
        np.vstack(coloursRectList['blue'])/255,
        np.vstack(coloursRectList['green'])/255,
        np.vstack(coloursRectList['yellow'])/255,
        np.vstack(coloursRectList['red'])/255,
        np.vstack(coloursRectList['black'])/255,

    print('len of temp', len(temp))
    print('type of temp', type(temp))
```

The output is as expected

```
len of temp 6
type of temp <class 'list'>
```

I prefer the first method as it would be more dynamic so that I can

```
EXTRACTED = np.array(np.vstack(temp))
```

I am wondering how to append numpy object to a list properly. Any help is appreciated.

---

Code tried to reproduce the error with numpy but it fails to reappear.
I am not sure what goes wrong.

```
import numpy as np

mylist = []
a = np.zeros(shape=(96, 93, 3))
b = np.vstack(a)/255
print(a.shape)
print(type(a))
print(b.shape)
print(type(b))
for i in range(5):
    mylist.append(b.copy())
    print(len(mylist))
```

Output

```
(96, 93, 3)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
(8928, 3)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: Could you please add a snippet of code to reproduce the error (one that I can run without importing OpenCV)?

Comment: I guess that the problem is outside of the shown code. Anyway, can you add a `print(temp)` to the "print"s and show its output in the question?

Comment: list .append() method is appending only a single element regardless of the type, you must have "temp" changed  in another place in the loop, please double check

Comment: @DaniMesejo I tried to reproduce the error but it doesn't work

Comment: @svfat thank you for your help! I figured out what went wrong. I thought 
`temp = temp2 = [] ` could create two empty lists

Comment: @user16971617 cool, I'll add this as the answer here

Comment: welcome. [mre], [ask], [tour]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python `list.append()` method appends only a single element regardless of its type, it's not possible to get the list length increased by two after a single `append` call. You must have "temp" changed in another place in the loop, please double-check.